# Removing commits from a remote

Tags: git, commit

I have a number of commits I would like to remove from a git remote. Can I do this by performing an interactive rebase and skipping the commits I don't want?

...and then force pushing to the remote?

Or can `revert` accept a list of commits to revert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this, by doing a rebase or anything else for that matter, on your local branch and then forcing the push.

```
git push --force origin master
```

But this is a really dangerous thing to do if this is a shared repo. In particular, if anyone has made a checkout, their tree is going to be all messed up when they try to pull again.

A better way to do this is to use `revert` which does the following (from the man page),

```
Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them. This requires your working tree to be clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).
```

Or in layman's terms, it makes new commits that undo the old ones. You can then push them to the remote without using `--force`. There will still be a record of all the old commits, and you can still `revert` or `reset` back to them, but it will be *safe*.

And yes, `revert` can take a range of commits to `revert`. The example from the man page is,

```
git revert -n master~5..master~2
```

Which will revert fifth to the third last commit. Using `revert` with a range does not create a new commit however, it just modifies the working tree. So you will have to make your own commit after.

It still might make someone grumpy when they have to merge with you though, as merging with a `revert` can sometimes make files and edits that were in use *go away*.

Comment: OK, so if I dont want to modify the pre-existing tree, does git have a feature that can create a new commit that exactly undoes the changes made in a set of specific commits?

Comment: Yes there is. I updated my answer to outline that solution. Sorry I should have put in there initially, I am a bit sleepy.